# How to access a java script variable in side PHP tags?

Tags: javascript, php

My Javascript function is as follows.

```
function fillValues(value){
   var i = value - 1;
   var b = "<?php echo $lieneageVal[2]['LineageNo'] ?>" 
   document.getElementById('lineageNo').value = b;
}
```

The PHP array `$lieneageVal[2]['LineageNo']` is already filled with values. I just want to know how to use the value in the variable `i` inside the PHP array. And I want to do this inside the Javascript function.

For example: `$lieneageVal[i]['LineageNo']`

Value `b` gets filled properly when I use `$lieneageVal[2]['LineageNo']`. But it doesn't work when I try `$lieneageVal[i]['LineageNo']`.

In simple terms, I need to use a Javascript variable inside a php array inside a Javascript function.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me how to use AJAX?

Comment: Be best to read the documentation for [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option is to encode your PHP array in JSON and then access the JSON value inside JavaScript. For example:

```
var lieneageVal = eval(<?php echo json_encode($lieneageVal); ?>);
function fillValues(value) {
   var i = value - 1;
   var b = lieneageVal[i]['LineageNo']; 
   document.getElementById('lineageNo').value = b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP is executed on server.** If you add php with javascript (javascript is executed on client navigator), it will be printed as a text.

If you want execute some php and to get result dynamically, try to understand `Ajax`.

> **with Javascript** : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/
>
> **with jQuery** : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to pass the php array into javascript array

Example

```
var values= new Array();
<?php for($i=0; $i<count($lieneageVal); $i++){ ?>
        values.push('<?php echo $lieneageVal[$i]['LineageNo']; ?>');
<?php } ?>

function fillValues(value){
   var i = value - 1;
   document.getElementById('lineageNo').value = values[i];
}
```